# aws boto3 paginator of list_images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

can someone please help me understand and do paginator codehere in this list_images code:
  When i run this to get list of images for ec2imagebuilder, in the responce i got the nexttoken so how to use this to list all images in next page/until end.

```
    client = boto3.client('imagebuilder')
    response = client.list_images(owner='Amazon')
    print(response)

Response (Trucated result):

{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'f4b9e178-b959-4e23-be57-0c234fbec69d', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Sun, 10 May 2020 21:53:55 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '8709', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'f4b9e178-b959-4e23-be57-0c234fbec69d', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'MVet5Hp0PHcFeaw=', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5eb877f2-9bec8ecc200f1394f6b0d340;Sampled=1'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'requestId': 'f4b9e178-b959-4e23-be57-0c234fbec69d', 'imageVersionList': [{'arn': 'arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-west-2:aws:image/amazon-linux-2-x86/2019.11.21', 'name': 'Amazon Linux 2 x86', 'version': '2019.11.21', 'platform': 'Linux', 'owner': 'Amazon', 'dateCreated': '2019-11-30T07:37:51.495Z'}, {'arn': 'arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-west-2:aws:image/windows-server-2012-r2-rtm-english-core-x86/2019.11.19', 'name': 'Windows Server 2012 R2 RTM English Core x86', 'version': '2019.11.19', 'platform': 'Windows', 'owner': 'Amazon', 'dateCreated': '2019-11-30T07:38:07.177Z'}], 'nextToken': 'eyxxxMS4xOSIsICJBY2NvdW50SWQiOiAiNTgwMDg3NjIzMDA1In0sICJtYXhfcmVzdWx0cyI6IDI1LCAia2V5X2NvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiB7IkFjY291bnRJZCI6IHsiQXR0cmlidXRlVmFsdWVMaXN0IjogWyI1ODAwODc2MjMwdddiOiBmYWxzZSwgInNjYW5faW5kZXhfZm9yd2FyZCI6IHRydWUsICJleHBpcmF0aW9uX2RhdGUiOiAxNTg5MjM0MDM1fQ=='}
```

Comment: You can alternatively use the provided `paginator` code: [Paginators — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein TIL. That's a great suggestion, John! Unfortunately, it seems like `list_images` is not supported yet. `botocore.exceptions.OperationNotPageableError: Operation cannot be paginated: list_images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/imagebuilder.html#imagebuilder.Client.list_images), you can use the following code snippet to list all images owned by Amazon.

```
client = boto3.client('imagebuilder')
response = client.list_images(owner='Amazon')
print(response['imageVersionList'])
while 'nextToken' in response:
    response = client.list_images(owner='Amazon', nextToken=response['nextToken'])
    print(response['imageVersionList'])
```