# Boto3 - AWS Appflow - list_flows not returning specified maximum number of flows

Tags: boto3, aws-sdk, amazon-appflow

The [AWS Boto3 Appflow documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appflow/client/list_flows.html) for **ListFlows** has a parameter *maxResults* which states:

> Specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Valid Range: Minimum value of 1. Maximum value of 100.

I currently have 37 flows, all active, and the **ListFlows** command with the parameter *maxResults* set to 100 has always returned all 37 flows in the response, until today. Now, it only returns 35 flows and a *nextToken* pagination token for next page of data.

I have tried this with AWS CLI and got the same result. I tried to search the net for information as to what has changed and how the *maxResults* param should work but have not found anything useful.

Does anyone have any clues as to why I am not getting all 37 flows when the parameter *maxResults* is set to 100?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rlhagerm Unfortunately, it seems like `list_flows` is not supported yet: `OperationNotPageableError: Operation cannot be paginated: list_flows`

However, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719428/aws-boto3-paginator-of-list-images) dealing with the similar issue which has helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options for paginating results with AWS Boto3 clients, see this [page that might be helpful](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html). Have you checked the PageSize? Be aware that some services have a max page size set that you cannot go over. Even if you aren't able to use a paginator, it could still be a page size issue in the list call.

Comment: How interesting. Thanks @rlhagerm, I will look in to this.